# how to sort a list of Object arrays in c#

Tags: c#, user-controls, windows-forms-designer

I'm working on a project that focuses on rearranging user controls in a page, for example, each user control will have like and dislike buttons, and these will decide its spot on the page compared to the other user controls statistics.
To do so, my user control constructor creates an array of info in the following way:

```
private Object[] matrControls = new Object[3];
        matrControls[0] = this; ///post
        matrControls[1] = 0; ///precent of votes
        matrControls[2] = 0; /// number of votes
```

then I have another method to return the array to the main code

```
public Object[] arrReturn()
        {
            return matrControls;
        }
```

In my code, I manually added 2 user controls to work and the reorganizing method, then "voted" and by that changed the amount and percent of it, and then I put them in a list of Object arrays:

```
private List<Object[]> ListPost = new List<Object[]>();
ListPost.Add(NewPost.arrReturn());
```

I want to organize firstly by the percent of votes (for example 6 likes, 4 dislikes = 60%), then if we have the same percent on 2 user controls (6 likes 4 dislikes & 60 likes 40 dislikes) to organize by the number of votes.
Both of these variables should be saved in my list.
My question is the following, How do I organize the list by the second and then the third variables, and then how would I change their spot on the page?
I would appreciate any help, Thanks.

Comment: That should not be an `Object[]` in the first place. It should be a class, designed for exactly that purpose.

Comment: don't throw **different** things into a **single** collection. If those things belong together, you should create a class for them and add instances of that class into your list/array.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create class instead of using `object[]`.

```
public class matrControls{
public int matrControls1 { get; set; }
public int matrControls2 { get; set; }
public int matrControls3 { get; set; }}

List<matrControls> matControlsList = new List<matrControls>();
matControlsList.Add(new matrControls{matrControls1=value1, matrControls2=value2, matrControls3=value3 });
matControlsList.Add(new matrControls{matrControls1=value1, matrControls2=value2, matrControls3=value3 });

var sortedList = matControlsList.OrderBy(control => control.matrControls1).ThenBy(control => control.matrControls2).ToList();
```

The above code shows how to create class and then how to add it to list and then sorting of the list as you require.

Comment: @Pizi If above answer addressed your issue then please mark it as an answer.